# Setting variable as returned list, doesn't seem to be doing anything

Tags: python

Setting variables as returned lists from functions that contain variables as a returned list doesn't seem to give me any output:

```
def get_wordlist(num, s):
    items_in_wordlist = database_get(num)
    print "Trying to get wordlist..."
    print items_in_wordlist
    items = []
    if s == 0:
        for item in items_in_wordlist:
            items.append((item[1]).decode("hex"))
        return items
    elif s == 1:
        for item in items_in_wordlist:
            items.append((item[2]).decode("hex"))
        return items

def get_wordlist_set(self, speed):
    global main_wordlist, main_wordlist_e
    print "Getting wordlist set..."
    #try:
    main_wordlist   = get_wordlist(speed, 1)
    print "Check (1) - Passed"
    main_wordlist_e = get_wordlist(speed, 0)
    print "Check (2) - Passed"
    return main_wordlist
```

"Check (*) - Passed" should be printed to the screen. However, All I am getting is "Getting wordlist set..." Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you clarify a bit more..you hv kind of got a tongue twister

Comment: What is happening in `database_get`? Based on what you say the observed output is, I'd guess something is not working right in there. What is the parameter `speed` set to, and what effect does it have on the call to `database_get`?

Comment: @sandinymyjoints Whoops, I thought I posted the database_get() function :P I am not getting any actual response from this function when it's called through get_wordlist_set. 'speed' is poorly referenced data in the sqlite3 database. I'm updating the original post. Sorry for the confusion :P

Comment: @sandinymyjoints You have answered my question! 'speed' was set to an integer in 'database_get()', and it was messing up the database_get() sql function. Sorry for being confusing! I'm not great with words. I fixed it by calling str(speed). Thank you :)

Comment: @abkai glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sandinmyjoints says, if you are seeing

`Getting wordlist set...`

But not

`Trying to get wordlist...`

It looks like

```
database_get(num)
```

isn't returning. It could also be that the same function name is used for a different function elsewhere. It might be a good idea to put a print *before* the call to `database_get`